# ATOI() results in "Exited Unexpectedly / Lost Connection"

Tags: objective-c, c, reference, xcode5

I am trying to run a simple command line program from Xcode 5. When I run it, I get the user input prompt in the shell, but then it crashes and gives me the error `Exited Unexpectedly / Lost Connection`

Here is my code. Can you please tell me if I am missing a library reference, or if there is something wrong in my code?

I also want to mention that in `Build Phases` --> `Link Binary With Libraries`, I make reference to `libreadline.dylib`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#import <readline/readline.h>
//#import <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    printf("Where should I start counting? ");

    int i;
    int countFrom = atoi(readline(NULL));

    for (i = countFrom; i >= 0; i -= 3) {
        printf("%d\n",i);

        if (i % 5 == 0){
            printf("Found one!\n");
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: `readline(NULL)` can return `NULL` in exceptional situations, but I doubt that applies here.  Maybe you want to check it though?

Comment: i tried replacing the `NULL` in `readline(NULL)` with a variable that i initialized to be `NULL`, but that behaved in the same way. if this is not what you meant, can you suggest another approach?

Comment: its the _return_ value from `readline()` that is the esoteric concern.   Is code passing `NULL` to `atoi()`?  BTW: I see nothing else wrong expect _maybe_ code should `#include <readline/readline.h>`.

Comment: thanks for your input. it still is not working, even when i did the following: (1) `char *userInput = readline(NULL); int countFrom = atoi(userInput);` and (2) `#include <readline/readline.h>`

Comment: "I get the user input prompt in the shell, but then it crashes", does this occur _before_ you have had a change to enter any data?  Else what data did you enter?

Comment: it only crashes after i enter the data into the shell. for example, i entered `50`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46617/discussion-between-chux-and-alex-v)

Answer (score 1):

Ran into a similar problem. Discovered that hitting the "enter" key with the numpad causes the readline(NULL) to crash. Got around that by hitting the "return" key. This is using the keyboard that came with the Mac. Hope this helps!